# vitamio service

Tags: java, android, sdk, ffmpeg, vitamio

I know that Vitamio will not work without the following condition:

```
 if (! io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs (this))
    return;
```

But how does it add to the `Service`.
I ran the demo I have everything works fine, but how to work in Servais

Answer (score 1):

1. You must add  InitActivity  to  AndroidManifest
2. It's will check if installed vitamio lib... if not, it'll install